# De-serialize a POJO using Lombok to send large JSON payload

Tags: java, json, builder, lombok, rest-assured

I'm a QA writing some tests using Rest Assured DSL.

This is my first attempt at using Lombok to deserialize a POJO for use in the JSON Payload.

This way of building my data object, Customer, seems very cumbersome.  As the test is failing with a 400, I assume I am not serializing it correctly and I'm unclear how to view the payload as JSON.

I'm not using an explicit mapping, so assume Rest Assured is using GSON by default.

Given my POJO:

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Customer {

    private String employeeCode;
    private String customer;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String title;
    private String dob;
    private String employeeId;

}
```

...And example payload I need to send:

```
{
    "employeeCode": "18ae56",
    "customer": {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Smith",
        "title": "Mr",
        "dob": "1982-01-08", 
        "employeeId": "2898373"
    }
}
```

My example test is:

```
 @BeforeClass
 public static void createRequestSpecification(){

    requestSpec = new RequestSpecBuilder()
            .setBaseUri("https://employee-applications.company.com")
            .setContentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .build();
}

   @Test
    public void createApplicationForNewCustomer(){

    Customer customer = Customer.builder().build();
    customer.setEmployeeCode("18ae56");
    customer.setFirstName("John");
    customer.setLastName("Smith");
    customer.setTitle("Mr");
    customer.setDob("1982-01-08");
    customer.setEmployeeId("2898373");

    given().
            spec(requestSpec).
    and().
            body(customer).
    when().
            post("/api/v6/applications").
    then().
            assertThat().statusCode(201);

}
```

Comment: I don't see any question here. You say "*I'm unclear if I am serializing it correctly*", well I would start by assuming that if your test passes, you are. Otherwise, what are you testing, if the input is irrelevant?

Comment: @Michael apologies, it wasn't clear; now updated.  I'm trying to debug, just looking to get there faster!

Comment: Your class definitely does not look right. There is nothing to suggest the nested structure. You need 2 classes: a new one called, say Message which contains 2 fields: `String employeeId`, and `Customer customer`. And then remove employeeId from customer class

Comment: Easy way to test: create a new test method along the lines of `System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(customerMessage))`

Comment: @Michael - I've added that point to my answer, I usually use the `ObjectMapper()` to test and thanks to you I now know another way :)

Comment: thank you both; greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POJO is incorrect and obviously the serialized JSON is not of the expected format

You should have two classes

Below is how your POJO should look like to generate the given JSON structure

```
    @Data
    public static class Customer {

        @JsonProperty("firstName")
        private String firstName;
        @JsonProperty("lastName")
        private String lastName;
        @JsonProperty("title")
        private String title;
        @JsonProperty("dob")
        private String dob;
        @JsonProperty("employeeId")
        private String employeeId;

    }

    @Data
    public static class Example {

        @JsonProperty("employeeCode")
        public String employeeCode;
        @JsonProperty("customer")
        public Customer customer;

    }
```

and your test method

```
Example e = new Example();
e.setEmployeeCode("18ae56");

Customer c = new Customer();
c.setFirstName("John");
c.setLastName("Smith");
c.setTitle("Mr");
c.setDob("1982-01-08");
c.setEmployeeId("2898373");

e.setCustomer(c);


given().spec(requestSpec).and().body(e).when().post("/api/v6/applications").then().assertThat()
```

Easiest ways to test :

```
String abc = new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(e);
System.out.println(abc);
```

or

```
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(e));
```

Comment: wonderful! thank you. Forgive my ignorance, I was unable to make the classes static so instantiated Example and Customer in the test class